# Cordova/Phonegap: get error when build a project

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I am trying to build a android project using Phonegap. But i got this error

```
C:\Users\ss\Documents\Phonegap\hello1>cordova build
Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\Users\ss\Documents\Phonegap\hello1\platforms\and
roid\cordova\build.bat""
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20
Running: C:\Users\ss\Documents\Phonegap\hello1\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuil
dDebug -b C:\Users\ss\Documents\Phonegap\hello1\platforms\android\build.gradle -
Dorg.gradle.daemon=true

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\ss\Documents\Phonegap\hello1\platforms\android\build.gradle
' line: 22

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'android']
   > Could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.708 secs

C:\Users\ss\Documents\Phonegap\hello1\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q
.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c "C:\Users\ss\Documents\Phonegap\h
ello1\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\Users\ss\Documents\Phonegap\
hello1\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true"
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 8

You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\ss\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordo
va\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:134:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

i am using 'cordova build' command to build android project.
please help what i missing? what should i do?

Comment: Possibly this issue ,It sometimes happens due some weird adb issue, open task manager end  adb process and keep trying or try restarting your system.

Comment: Did you upgrade your cordova platform recently ? , if so ,  create a cordova project from scratch and just test if you can build that newly created project.    If there is no problem with the new one,  upgrading cordova platform has made your project crashed somehow.